# Who to send response data in data field in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

What I need is to send heroes Object in "data" field for the client.

This is my NodeJS code:

```
app.get('/heroes', (req, res) => {
    getHeroes().then(function (heroes) {
        res.json(heroes);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
});
```

heroes is a JavaScript Object that I get from MongoDB.

The client see something like this:

```
_body: "[{"name":"dsfsdf","id":"1"},{"name":"fhghfgh","id"…{"name":"sdff","id":"1"}
```

Who to store heroes in data property instead _body?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share expected output as well !

Comment: Don't forget to respond to the HTTP request in the error case, otherwise the request will just hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The `response.json()` function takes in a JSON object. You have supplied an array of JSON objects rather than a JSON object itself. You need to declare the JSON item you want to allocate the data to. Without the explicit declaration, it is defaulting to `_body`.

You could do something like this:

```
app.get('/heroes', (req, res) => {
    getHeroes().then(function (heroes) {
        res.json({ "data": heroes });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but whaty I need is to store heroes in data response porperty, not this: _body: "{"data":[{"name":"dsfsdf","id":"1"}

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get "_body". Assuming that your code is returning it into `_body` then use `res.json({ "data": heroes._body })`

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/heroes', (req, res) => {
    getHeroes().then(function (heroes) {
        res.json({"data": heroes._body });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, explaining your code would be great for others reading your answer.